# Grpc - listener implemetation on client side

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc, listener, grpc-python

I have a proto as below, now as a client i send the mentioned request and get empty response from the grpc server

```
package login;

option java_package = "com.some.com"; // Package name for all generated classes
option java_multiple_files = true; // Generate multiple files instead of a single file

service Game{
  rpc listen(test) returns (EmptyResponse) {}
}

message EmptyResponse{

}

message test {
  string name = 1;
}
```

Post this the server processes and responds back with another json as response asynchronously to the client. Now on client side to capture this response(since its async) do we need to implement a listener explicitly by opening a port on client side / is there inbuilt way in grpc which does this.

Comment: It's not clear which gRPC language this is about. The tags say python and grpc-python but the options used in the proto file indicate Java. Pls clarify